# Java Polymorphism: non-final method Invocation

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
//employee class
public class Employee {

protected String psrn;

public Employee(String n)
{
    psrn =n;
}

public String getPSRN()
{
    return ("Emp:"+psrn);
}

void computeSimilarity(Employee t)
{
    System.out.println("Emp::compute---"+t.getPSRN());
}

}

//student class


public class Student extends Employee{
public Student(String n) {
        super(n);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public String getPSRN()
{
    return("Std:"+psrn);
}
void computeSimilarity(Student t)
{
    System.out.println("Std::compute---"+t.getPSRN());
}
}

//tester class

public class Tester {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Employee e0=new Employee("0");
Employee e=new Student("1");
Student s=new Student("2");

e.computeSimilarity(s);
s.computeSimilarity(e);
s.computeSimilarity(s);
s.computeSimilarity(e0);

}

}
```

The output comes out to be:

> Emp::compute---Std:2
>
> Emp::compute---Std:1
>
> Std::compute---Std:2
>
> Emp::compute---Emp:0

But by my understanding,it should come out to be

> Emp::compute---Std:2
>
> Emp::compute---Std:1
>
> Std::compute---Std:2
>
> Std::compute---Emp:0

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you got an unexpected result for

```
s.computeSimilarity(e0);
```

Your expectation was that *Student.computeSimilarity(Student)* would be called, however *Employee.computSimiarity(Employee)* was called.

The reason *Employee.computSimiarity(Employee)* was called is because the computeSimilarity method in the Student class is not an override of the base class method.

In order to override a method, you must maintain the exact signature.

```
void computeSimilarity(Employee t)
```

and

```
void computeSimilarity(Student s)
```

are different signatures.

========================

**Suggestion for you**: Make use of Java's @Override annotation.  If you put this annotation on a method that you intend to serve as an override, the compiler will ensure that this is the case.  Had you put that annotation on the method in the Student class, the compiler would have given you an error message.

So in your Student class, you would have:

```
@Override
void computeSimilarity(Student t) {
    System.out.println("Std::compute---"+t.getPSRN());
}
```

which the compiler would flag as an error, and you would correct the error with the following change:

```
@Override
void computeSimilarity(Employee t) {
    System.out.println("Std::compute---"+t.getPSRN());
}
```

and then you would have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following method in Employee:

```
void computeSimilarity(Employee t)
```

and this one in Student:

```
void computeSimilarity(Student t)
```

The second method *does not* override the first method. It's an entirely separate method that just happens to have the same name.

Why not? Imagine if it did override. Then this code would work:

```
class Employee {
    void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
class Student extends Employee {
    void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s.length());
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e = new Student();
        e.print(e);
    }
}
```

and it would somehow call `print(String s)` with an argument that is a `Student`. That shouldn't be allowed to happen - and, in fact, it's *not* allowed to happen, because the method in Student doesn't override the method in Employee.

There are some languages where the code above would call the Student method if the argument was a string, and the Employee method otherwise. Java does not do that.